# What does airmon-ng when enabling promiscuous mode on a wireless card

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

I am capturing the traffic on my domestic wireless network using wireshark. For that, I had to: - set up a new monitor interface from my wireless interface using airmon-ng script; - enable promiscous mode on my monitor interface in wireshark.

I don't fully understand what I have done, neither why it was necessary. Google didn't provide any relevant answer since a search with airmon-ng or aircrack-ng keywords leads to tutorials to crack WEPs protected networks... I found the source code of airmon-ng which lead me to wander aimlessly into my /sys/devices.

I understand that by default, wireless cards filter packets so that only those sent to it (proper MAC address, or broadcast) are forwarder to the system. Here are my questions:

1. Is this hardware or software filtering (driver?)?
2. What does airmon-ng?
3. Why isn't it possible to enable monitor mode on some devices? Is it a problem with drivers?
4. Why is it necessary to create another interface?
5. Is there any parallel with an internet interface receiving traffic from a hub? I mean are packets 'pre-filtered' in that configuration?
6. hat is the purpose of 'promiscuous mode' checkbox in wireshark if all the work is done at a lower level?

I am sorry for those noob questions, this isn't my field ;-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that promisc mode and monitor mode are different things in Wi-Fi:

- "Promiscuous" mode disables filtering of L2 frames with a different destination MAC. But in Wi-Fi, you're still limited to receiving only same-network data.
- "Monitor" mode disables filtering at L1, so that you see *anything* that the radio is capable of receiving (including other networks; control frames like beacons; and sometimes even stuff from other channels).

(Meanwhile, in hubbed Ethernet, it's just a single "promiscuous" mode.)

> Is this hardware or software filtering (driver?)?

Usually it's hardware-based – saves a considerable amount of power compared to CPU-based filtering.

> What does airmon-ng [do]?

With modern nl80211-based wireless drivers, it's roughly equivalent to:

```
iw phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor
...
iw mon0 interface del
```

A lot of code in there is just for compatibility with older drivers (WEXT and weird stuff).

> Why isn't it possible to enable monitor mode on some devices? Is it a problem with drivers?

It varies – sometimes the driver doesn't support it, and sometimes the firmware on the device itself doesn't allow it.

> Why is it necessary to create another interface?

That's just how nl80211 is architectured. It *might* be possible to switch a managed interface to monitor mode though.

> Is there any parallel with an internet interface receiving traffic from a hub? I mean are packets 'pre-filtered' in that configuration?

Yes, it's a bit similar. Both Wi-Fi and hubbed Ethernet are *shared-medium* networks; all hosts receive everything and just throw away what they don't want.

> [W]hat is the purpose of 'promiscuous mode' checkbox in wireshark if all the work is done at a lower level?

See above – it's a much older setting and can still be useful for Ethernet or other connection types.